# Java process crashes - Need help to analyze the thread dump

Tags: java

Got a thread dump for the java process always crashes - The symptom is that the application exists without any warnings or errors.
The thread dump was made when java application was launching.
Can anyone help to find any potential cause here? Thanks

---

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_10-b03 mixed mode):

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000100383cd0 nid=0x19 runnable [0x0000000000000000..0x0000000000000000]

"CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000100382c60 nid=0x18 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000..0xffffffff298fdcf8]

"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000100380440 nid=0x17 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000..0xffffffff29afdf18]

"AdapterThread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000010037f570 nid=0x16 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000..0x0000000000000000]

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000010037e560 nid=0x15 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000..0x0000000000000000]

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000100367820 nid=0x14 in Object.wait() [0xffffffff2a0ff000..0xffffffff2a0ff628]
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0xffffffff5c400ad0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:116)
    - locked <0xffffffff5c400ad0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:132)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000100366fb0 nid=0x13 in Object.wait() [0xffffffff2a2ff000..0xffffffff2a2ff7a8]
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0xffffffff5c400950> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:474)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked <0xffffffff5c400950> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x0000000100121cd0 nid=0x1 runnable [0xffffffff7fff2000..0xffffffff7fff56f0]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDProcessor.attributeDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanAttlistDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDecls(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:146)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$2.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:612)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:711)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:618)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:468)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
    at com.lehman.cats.common.mismarketsharereport.history.MarketShareHistoricalLoader.<clinit>(MarketShareHistoricalLoader.java:43)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000100363240 nid=0x12 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000100122d00 nid=0x2 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001a7440 nid=0x3 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001a7f40 nid=0x4 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001a8a40 nid=0x5 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001a9540 nid=0x6 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001aa040 nid=0x7 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001aab40 nid=0x8 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001ab660 nid=0x9 runnable 

"GC task thread#8 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001ac160 nid=0xa runnable 

"GC task thread#9 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001acc60 nid=0xb runnable 

"GC task thread#10 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001ad760 nid=0xc runnable 

"GC task thread#11 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001ae260 nid=0xd runnable 

"GC task thread#12 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001aed60 nid=0xe runnable 

"GC task thread#13 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001af860 nid=0xf runnable 

"GC task thread#14 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001b0360 nid=0x10 runnable 

"GC task thread#15 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000001001b0e60 nid=0x11 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000100198170 nid=0x1a waiting on condition
```

Comment: You need to show us the JAVA code.

Comment: Looks like you're creating a logger for a class which is triggering a load of a badly malformed XML logging configuration file.  Does running with `-verbose` tell you which logging file that is?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  When is the thread dump generated?  Was it at some point when the application was starting but then later it crashes?  If this is the case then I would make sure that all of your exceptions are being caught and dumped to the console or log files.  Analyzing a previous thread dump is not going to help much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems MarketShareHistoricalLoader.java:43 line causing this issue. It seems XMLDTDLoader loader failing in building grammar for your inputsource. You may need to findout alterantives like DTD disable etc., Here is a link for [understanding java thread dump](http://www.javasanity.org/understandingthreaddumps)  and [disable DTD validaton](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2009/10/25/disable-dom-dtd-validation/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probably misconfigured log4j logger.